# How to know that IMS registration is happened in SIM1 or SIM2 via adb logs for android device

Tags: adb, lte, cellular-automata, ims

How to know that `IMS` registration is happened in `SIM1` or `SIM2` via `ADB` logs.

If i have attached `SIM1` to `VoLTE` and `SIM2` to `3G` , from runtime `ADB` logs how can i verify that.
I need a solution to create for my automation script, so it can detect the `IMS` registration during runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the output using following command:

```
adb shell logcat | grep ims_reg_state
```

Comment: Hello Filipe, I have accepted your answer in formatting code using {} icon. Next time you take time to answer, try to format code or command as code so that answer is more readable. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! It was my first answer and I'll be more careful next time